# Popularity ranking algorithm based on votes from 1 to 5

Tags: mysql, algorithm, ranking

I'm developing a new Website where there's some "entities" to vote.

Every vote could be a number between 1 and 5 where 1 is the worst vote and 5 is the best vote.

Now, in the same website I have a "Popular entities chart" where I list the most popular "entities" based on their vote.

Now, I can't do a simply arithmetic average because an "entity" with one vote of 5 could have the same ranking as an "entity" with 100 votes of 5.

I thought about storing for every "entity" not ony the arithmetic average but also the numbers of votes and doing an SQL Query where I order by number of votes and arithmetic average but seems that after this, an entity with many votes of 1 could get popularity (when it isn't popular).

What algorithm could I use?

Comment: I've proposed my idea about how to achieve something like what I want "doing an SQL Query where I order by number of votes and arithmetic average".

Simply, if I'm searching here is because i **don't have** any better idea, so I'm searching some confrontation here.

I suppose that StackOverflow isn't only a place where to post code with bad syntax that needs to be fixed. You're a little too pedantic.

Comment: Start with [Bayes_estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator). And as mentioned above: it's a design-decision one has to make, given as much a-priori info as possible.

Comment: One simple approach that behaves better than directly taking the average is to consider that each entity starts with a certain number of "3" votes (_e.g._ 100 such votes), and then take the average by including both these default votes, as well as the actual ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a basic solution try `order by [average vote] desc, [vote count] desc` this way out of two entities with the same average, the one with 100 votes will go above the one with 1 vote, but one with average of 4.5 will never go above one with average of 5.

**Edit 1**

If you *want* 100 vote average of 4.5 to win against 10 vote average of 5, why not count votes ignoring 1, 2 and 3, or [count of votes 4 and 5] - [count of votes 1 and 2]? This way count of *positive* votes would pull entities up in ranking.

**Edit 2**

You might want to give extra importance to recent votes. Something might have changed about an entity that changed user opinion of it. Could build another average of votes made last month and adjust final ranks based on it.

**Edit 3**

What about calculate a [popularityScore] column and just order by it?

```
-- sum instead of average
-- square root of sum will reduce importance of vote count a bit
select
    entity,
    sqrt(sum(vote - 3)) as popularityScore
from Votes
group by entity
order by rank desc

-- 50 votes of 5 -> popularityScore = 12.25
-- 100 votes of 4 -> popularityScore = 10
-- 200 votes of 4 -> popularityScore = 14.14
-- 2000 votes of 4 -> popularityScore = 44.72
-- 2000 votes of 5 -> popularityScore = 63.25
-- 100000000 votes of 3 -> popularityScore = 0
```

Could calculate same score for last month and add it to this value.

Comment: Doesn't this let an entity with 1000 votes of 1 go up more than a server with 500 votes of 5?

Comment: The edit of your reply isn't so bad, a good approach could be like consider the group {1, 2, 3} = DOWN and {4, 5} = UP

Comment: `order by [average vote] desc, [vote count] desc` will order by average and _then_ do a sub-order by count. There's no way this will have lots of votes of 1 higher than single vote of 5, just like 1000 votes of 4 will go below one vote of 5.

Comment: "1000 votes of 4 will go below one vote of 5" is what I want to avoid.

At this point I think that is better order first by [vote count] and after by [average vote]